# DotNet.Highcharts not working with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, highcharts

I downloaded and am trying to get DotNet.Highcharts working with Visual Studio 2010.  I followed the instruction found at [DotNet.Highcharts](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/) and it is not quite working.  I am getting errors saying it can't find certain files.  I did everything exactly as described in the link.  Does anyone have more detailed instructions or have any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may have a problem similar to what I was experiencing.  See post [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607931/integrate-highcharts-in-visual-studio-2010) for what I did to correct it.  it appears you may not have the files in the right location.

Comment: By the way, you may want to search for related questions before posting a question.

Comment: Wow, 7 views and 1 answer that fast.  This is a really active forum.  I appologize for not looking at other questions first.  I am a noob and will not make that mistake again.  Thanks for setting me straight and the answer.  I did have the files in a folder and that is why I was getting errors. Just like in the question you linked.  Thanks again.